# Unsure how strcpy works in this situation

Tags: c, strcpy

I am very new to C and working through a project as a way to help motivate me to learn. I was having a hard time getting the output from an sh popen. After much searching and hours of trial and i stumbled across a very old post where they used

```
strcpy(str + size - 1,buf);
```

This was the first and only example of this i could find and it is working. It looks like it overwrites the termination character at the end of str with what's in buf. Is that safe? I still havent fully gotten the grasp of how it stores all of this data and changing that number on the end to anything higher than a +2 causes segmentation faults or invalid next size. The full code is below

```
int dns_probe(char * hostname)
{
    char * digLoop[4] = {"ns ","a ","cname ","mx "};
    int i;
    char outage[1];
    char *str = NULL;
    char *temp = NULL;
    unsigned int size = 1;
    unsigned int strlength;

    for ( i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        char *digcmd = concatCMD(digLoop[i],hostname);

        FILE * dig = popen(digcmd,"r");
        char bufer[256];
        while(fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),dig) != 0){

            strlength = strlen(buf);

            temp = realloc(str, size + strlength);
            str = temp;

            strcpy(str + size - 1,buf);
            size += strlength;
        }

       pclose(dig);
       free(digcmd);

    }
    printf("%s",str);
}
```

Really just wanna make sure I am not setting myself up with problems down the road.

Comment: I guess you have error checking between `temp = realloc()` and `str = temp`, and just removed it for clarity?  Otherwise, you could be writing through a null pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is safe as long as the `realloc()` ensures that the buffer is large enough (and it does).

Before the `realloc()` you might have:

```
     +---+---+---+----+
buf: | f | o | o | \0 | size=4
     +---+---+---+----+
```

Then let's assume `"bar"` is read, so that:

```
strlength = strlen("bar") = 3
```

Then `temp` will be `realloc()`ated to length 4 + 3 = 7:

```
      +---+---+---+----+---+---+---+
temp: | f | o | o | \0 | ? | ? | ? | 
      +---+---+---+----+---+---+---+
```

Then `buf` is set to `temp` (there should be `NULL`-checks here, btw).

Finally we `strcpy()` `"bar"`  to `buf + 4 - 1`, i.e. `buf[3]`:

```
      +---+---+---+---+---+---+----+
 buf: | f | o | o | b | a | r | \0 |
      +---+---+---+---+---+---+----+
```

Clearly this buffer is the same size as before, and no character outside the buffer has been touched.

Comment: Okay, so the realloc() on temp carries over when i str = temp;  This helps alot Thank you. (Not enough rep to upvote this)

Answer (score 0):

```
        `temp = realloc(str, size + strlength);`
```

//buf of str is re-allocated to length (size+strlength),and then more bytes are written to this newly allocated. with an initial length 1, buffer of str is safe here.
However, strcpy is highly recommended which is safer.

And here, https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcpy.htm you can find some simple cases for study.